# NoMethodError in SessionsController#destroy undefined method `forget' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Working through Rails Tutorial by M. Hartl Ch 8 Log in, Log out

When attempting to log out of my application, I receive the error message given in the title of my question.

I'm very new to this, but I think this means that the `forget` instance method defined in `models/user.rb` and called in `SessionsHelper` is being called on `user` which for some reason is nil. Here's the snippet I'm talking about in `SessionsHelper`:

```
#Found in SessionHelper.  Forgets persistent session
def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_tolken)
end
```

And here's the definition of the `forget` instance method:

```
#Found in class models/user.rb
def forget
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
end
```

I don't know why user would be nil when called in `SessionsHelper`.  Here are the full files, including `SessionsController`, `SessionsHelper`, and `User`.

I hope I was clear and used the right terminology. Let me know if I need to clarify.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        log_in user # Log the user in and redirect to the user's showpage
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_to user # same as user_url(user)
    else
        # Show error message
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Wrong email or password' 
        render 'new'
    end
    end

    def destroy
    log_out # if logged_in?    # not logging out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

XXXXXXXXXX

```
module SessionsHelper

# Logs in given user
def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end

# Remembers a user in a persistant session
def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end

#Forgets persistent session
def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_tolken)
end


# Returns the current logged-in user (if any)
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id]) # CAREFUL! (not ==). Read if session of user_id exists
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    else (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in(user)
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end

# Returns true if the user is logged-in, else false
def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

# logs out current user
def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    forget(current_user)
    @current_user = nil
end
end
```

XXXXXXXXXX

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token

  before_save {email.downcase!}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string. Used to make hashed password of user in fixture model for login integration testing                                                        
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns random token for remembering users via cookies
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persisten sessions
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

end
```

Thank you

Comment: The `current_user` method is returning nil when it shouldn't. I suspect this line: `else (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])`, I've never known `else` to take an argument, so it looks fishy to me. Perhaps `elsif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `log_out` method is deleting the session **before** forgetting the user. This causes an error because `forget` takes `current_user` as a parameter and `current_user` uses the session to determine who the current user is:

```
    if (user_id = session[:user_id]) # This will attempt to assign user_id based on the value of session[:user_id], but will fail since the session was deleted
```

You need to delete the session **after** forgetting the user.
Change your `log out` method from this:

```
def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    forget(current_user)
    @current_user = nil
end
```

To this:

```
def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
end
```

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue.  It's very obvious now that you pointed it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `current_user` method is returning nil, and that is throwing the error further down the line.

There is a typo in your `current_user` method. Change the `else` to `elsif` and it should most likely fix the issue.

If that does not fix it, make sure the method is exactly the same as in [Listing 8.57 of the rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-branch_no_raise) ; the same is included below:

```
# Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I do remember the book instructing to use elseif in this situation.  I am getting this error in the browser when I run it however

NoMethodError in SessionsController#destroy
undefined method `elseif' for #<SessionsController:0x007f8f2492e6f8>

@BigRon's solution fixed the original problem, but I would like to understand why this isn't working.